# How to generate all possible functions combinations

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

Assume that I have 3 functions like this (total 10 functions in reality).

```
f1[x_] := 3 x;
f2[x_] := x^2 - 1;
f3[x_] := 2 x + 5;
```

Now I want to generate all possible combinations like this:

```
f1[f2[f3[a]]], f1[f3[f2[a]]], f2[f1[f3[a]]], f2[f3[f1[a]]], f3[
 f1[f2[a]]], f3[f2[f1[a]]]
```

How can I do that?
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
#3[#2[#1[5]]] & /@ Map[Sequence @@ &, Permutations[{f1, f2, f3}]]
```

Comment: `Compose @@@ Replace[Permutations@{f1, f2, f3}, {fp__, fl_} :> {fp, fl[a]}, {1}]`

Answer (score 12):

```
ClearAll[allCompositions]
allCompositions[a_] := Through @ (Permutations @* Composition)[##] @ a &;
```

***Examples:***

```
allCompositions[x][f1, f2, f3]
```

> ```
> {f1[f2[f3[x]]], f1[f3[f2[x]]], f2[f1[f3[x]]], f2[f3[f1[x]]], 
>  f3[f1[f2[x]]], f3[f2[f1[x]]]}
> ```

```
allCompositions[x] @@ {f1, f2, f3}
```

> ```
> {f1[f2[f3[x]]], f1[f3[f2[x]]], f2[f1[f3[x]]], f2[f3[f1[x]]], 
>  f3[f1[f2[x]]], f3[f2[f1[x]]]}
> ```

```
f1[x_] := 3 x;
f2[x_] := x^2 - 1;
f3[x_] := 2 x + 5;

allCompositions[x][f1, f2, f3] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> {12 (2 + x) (3 + x), 9 + 6 x^2,  4 (7 + 3 x) (8 + 3 x),
> -1 + (5 + 6 x)^2, -1 + 6 x^2, 3 + 18 x^2}
> ```

```
allCompositions[5][f1, f2, f3]
```

> ```
> {672, 159, 2024, 1224, 149, 453}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[allCompositions2]
allCompositions2[f__] := Through @ (Permutations@*Composition)[f] @ ## &;

allCompositions2[h1, h2, h3] @ x
```

> ```
> {h1[h2[h3[x]]], h1[h3[h2[x]]], h2[h1[h3[x]]], h2[h3[h1[x]]], 
>  h3[h1[h2[x]]], h3[h2[h1[x]]]}
> ```

```
allCompositions2[h1, h2][x, y, z]
```

> ```
> {h1[h2[x, y, z]], h2[h1[x, y, z]]}
> ```

```
allCompositions2[f1, f2, f3] @ 5
```

> ```
> {672, 159, 2024, 1224, 149, 453}
> ```

Comment: This is nice but how would you pass a function to the function? That would make a general solution. I tried `#[5]&[f1]` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: How would you implement the example `#[5]&[f1]`? The problem above is solved but I want to know a general solution for any function.

Comment: or this `#3[#2[#1[5]]] &[g,h,k]` to make `g[h[[k[5]]]`

Comment: `Compose[##, 5] &[g, h, k]` or `Composition[##][5] &[g, h, k]`?

Comment: what if I have a main function with arguments g, h, k and inside this main function I do various things?

Comment: For example `main[g_, h_, k_]: = g[3] + h[2] + k[1]`;

Answer (score 11):

```
Composition[##][x] & @@@ Permutations[{f1, f2, f3}]
```

> ```
> {f1[f2[f3[x]]], f1[f3[f2[x]]], f2[f1[f3[x]]], 
>  f2[f3[f1[x]]], f3[f1[f2[x]]], f3[f2[f1[x]]]}
> ```

Comment: It works but just an additional question. How would you write it as passing function names to a function?

Comment: Very elegant (+1).

Comment: @anhnha If I understand your question you should examine what `##` does, i.e. look at [`SlotSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html).  Otherwise you should explain more clearly what you mean.